# clang-tidy: Ignore specific folder from clang-tidy analysis

Tags: c++, regex, clang-tidy

I have the following directory structure

├── .clang-format

├── .clang-tidy

├── external

├── scripts

└── source

For my clang tidy execution I want to only include headers from the `source` folder and exclude ones from `external`. The following setting does not work for either match `HeaderFilterRegex: '^(source)+(?!.*external).*'` The format of the [regex is correct](https://regex101.com/r/SVxrIc/1/)

In the `.clang-tidy` file If I only include `HeaderFilterRegex: '^(?!.*external).*'` it excludes the `external` folder but doesn't include the `source` header files

and similarly if I only include this check `HeaderFilterRegex: '(src/)'` it doesn't exclude the external files.

**Update**

Ok this seems like it is related to the fact clang uses Posix ERE regex flavor (thanks @pablo285) and this does not support negative lookahead. I would have thought this was a fairly standard requirement for using clang-tidy, excluding certain folders from the analysis.

Comment: You are using wrong regex flavour - you linked to PCRE but clang uses Posix ERE.

Comment: @pablo285 Oh I was not even aware of that, what specifically is the difference

Comment: @pablo285 Is it even possible to do negative lookaheads using Posix

Comment: I'm not an expert on regex unfortunately, I just happen to know this since I had a similar problem in the past. Try to post a question in `regex` tag.

Comment: See the Q&A at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75586089/1743580 for a workaround.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clang-tidy: Exclude specific dir from analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74349432/clang-tidy-exclude-specific-dir-from-analysis)