# clang-tidy: Exclude specific dir from analysis

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy, linter

I'm using `clang-tidy` in a medium-size project with the following three folders:

```
srcA
srcB
external
```

I'm trying to exclude `external` folder from the analysis, but with no luck.
The command I'm using is:

```
clang-tidy $SRC -p build/ --extra-arg=-ferror-limit=0'
```

with

```
SRC=srcA/file.cpp srcA/fileN.cpp srcB/file.cpp srcB/fileN.cpp ...
```

and a compilation database under `build/` generated by `cmake`.
Note that SRC doesn't contain any `external` file, only from `srcA` and `srcB` (both .cpp and .hpp). Also, and obviusly, some files under `srcA` and `srcB` are using libraries under `external`.

The 80% of the errors from `clang-tidy` comes from `external/` files, which I can't fix because there're third party libraries.

Below, the `.clang-tidy` file I'm using:

```
Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming'
WarningsAsErrors: "*"
CheckOptions:
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase, value: CamelCase }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassMethodCase, value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.VariableCase, value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.PrivateMemberPrefix, value: m_ }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.PrivateMemberCase, value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.FunctionCase, value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.MethodCase, value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ParameterCase, value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.MemberCase, value: camelBack }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.EnumCase, value: CamelCase }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.StructCase, value: CamelCase }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.TemplateParameterCase, value: CamelCase }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.TypeAliasCase, value: CamelCase }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.TypedefCase, value: CamelCase }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ConstexprVariableCase, value: UPPER_CASE }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.ConstantCase, value: UPPER_CASE }
FormatStyle: 'file'
```

I know this question is already posted here, but I've tried the proposed solutions and none of them worked. For example, I've tried using `HeaderFilterRegex`, matching only the desired files, and didn't work.

Am I missing something? Is this even possible to achieve (I've read in some page that this is a known bug from `clang-tidy`)?

Comment: Have you try to put a "nul" (i.e `Checks: '-*'`) .clang-tidy in external directory (to take precedence over the root one)?

Comment: Didn't work @Jarod42, thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi all. I am facing a similar issue. I need to exclude my conan package folder which is /root/.conan/data folder. I can't implement the workaround mentioned there. I tried HeaderFilterRegex and --header-filter, so far none of the negation regex worked for me. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I found the following workaround.

Project structure:

```
- project/.clang-tidy
- project/srcA/
- project/srcB/
- project/external/
- project/external/.clang-tidy
```

Top-level `project/.clang-tidy`:

```yaml
# File: project/.clang-tidy

Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming'
WarningsAsErrors: "*"
#
# ...more configs here...
#

# IMPORTANT: Set HeaderFilterRegex as shown below.
# Do not set it to '.*', for example.
HeaderFilterRegex: ''
```

Then create a separate `.clang-tidy` file in the folder you want to ignore/exclude, with the following contents.

`project/external/.clang-tidy`:

```yaml
# File: project/external/.clang-tidy

# Disable all checks in this folder.
Checks: '-*'
```

I then run clang-tidy with the command:

```
$ fd '\.(c|h)$' -X clang-tidy {} -p build/ --quiet
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it's impossible at the moment. It seems the only possible solution: list all the allowed paths except `external/` in `HeaderFilterRegex` in `.clang-tidy`.

See the discussion thread ["clang-tidy Negative Lookahead Support"](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/clang-tidy-negative-lookahead-support/39007).

Comment: I've tried that as well but didn't work either.